Why did my answer get deleted?


I have a question about my Bitcoin Stack Exchange post: Bittrex API rate limit

My post answered the question "what is Bittrex's API rate limit". Specifically, my answer stated: "...to limit to 1 request per second" which answers the question.
The moderator (perhaps a bot) deleted my post stating "This does not answer the question but rather appears to be commentary."
Was my answer too verbose? Does the information given somehow not answer the question? Why did my answer get deleted?
Also note that I cannot actually post comments because my reputation is currently too low. But in any case, I think what I wrote is more appropriate as an answer rather than a comment (cf this meta post).

The wording of your answer made it sound like you were talking about the OP of that question which thus sounds like commentary. The usage of "they" was a bit vague (generally I think it's clearer to refer specifically to a person rather than use a pronoun, e.g. "the poster") and I didn't quite catch what the answer actually meant.
Further review of the answer shows that it should not be deleted. I have undeleted it.
